# Using Countdown timer and running it in a service while updating a textview

Tags: android, service, countdowntimer

As the title suggests, I am using a countdown timer in my app and I want the user to be able to exit the app while having the countdown timer run in the background and update the textview according. I'm assuming a service will be needed but I don't know how to implement a service to the countdown timer within my application. The code block provided below will state the problems I am having with comments.

## Update

```
public class CountDownService extends Service {

    TextView timeTextView;
    int data;


    public  String hms;
    public CountDownAct countDownAct;
    public CountDownTime countDownTimer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      data = intent.getIntExtra("the", 0);
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTime(data,1000 );
        countDownTimer.start();


        return START_STICKY; 


    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {

        Log.i("CountDownService", "Stop Service");
        return super.stopService(name);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        countDownTimer.cancel();

    }

    public class CountDownTime extends CountDownTimer {


        /**
         * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
         *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
         *                          is called.
         * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
         *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
         */
        public CountDownTime(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



            long millis = millisUntilFinished;

            // this is the format which reads the time data from the user and makes it readable
            hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));


            //the textview is updated with each tick that goes by and contains the current time that is left
            // I want this text to be updated even if the user exits the app. The textview has to be updated with the current time left until finishing

//            countDownAct.timeTextView.setText(hms);
            CountDownAct.timeTextView.setText(hms);
            Log.i("CountDownService", hms);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent goBack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), alarmtimefinished.class);
            goBack.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            goBack.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(goBack);

        }




    }

}
```

### CatLog

```
07-24 18:27:41.629  19054-19054/com.personalproject.peter.timerapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.personalproject.peter.timerapp.CountDownService$CountDownTime.onTick(CountDownService.java:79)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: if the user `finish()`es your `Activity` so what `TextView` do you want to update?

Comment: timeTextView within the ontick method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have been using services lately and its pretty simple,, just make a class that extends Service ,, check this : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

put your code in onStartCommand method

why dont you make an object of the timer inside the service class

if you want your service to do something repeatedly use this :

```
Handler mHandler;
private void doSomething() {


    scheduleNext(10*1000); // time in m seconds 
    //your code here



}

private void scheduleNext(int time) {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            doSomething();

        }
    },time);
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: I tried but I received an error saying that the statement was unreachable check the updated code above

Comment: because you have a return statement above that line,,,,
make : return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); the last statement in the method

Comment: Ok so I also got it working but I am having trouble updating the textview in the service. can you help? I have updated the code block

Comment: does it give you an exception ? show me the catlog please

Comment: did you destroy the activity after running t ? because it cant find the textView so you are basically trying to change something that does not exist , anyhow the text view should be appearing on the screen to do stuff on it, so make sure that the textView you are dealing with is on the screen at that time

Comment: I got the textview working now;however if I exit the activity and re enter it, it starts another service and thus another  countdown timer. Would you know how to solve this?

Comment: you want the service to do the job for 1 time only ? 
this may not be the best solution but i would use a flag , set true once the service starts , so the activity will check if the flag is true , it will not start another one , however set the flag to false when the service is done working

Comment: what type of flags would I put like NEW_Task

Comment: I have updated the service code to show what my current situation looks like

Comment: i was thinking of a static boolean variable in your counter class , when you start your service change it to true , make the the class check the variable before it starts the service if its true then there is a service already running , when the service is done working , change the variable to false so the activity will start another service next time it checks the variable , got it ?